# Why am I getting different bytes every time I encrypt with AWS KMS CMK?

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, encryption, sdk

I am trying to encrypt my sensitive data like user email address to the database using aws kms cmk. I am using aws SDK in java.

I have encrypted the field and stored in data base.

I can also decrypt the data.

But the main problem comes when I have to query the data...
As I am getting back the aws sdkbytes and I am converting it to base 68 and storing it.

Why does aws always return the different SDK bytes for the same data after encryption?
I can't search simply through the data.
I have to bring all the list and decrypt the data and then match the data.
It is taking a lot of time.

Please suggest me the good way to encrypt the data using aws cmk keys.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: You probably mean base 64.

Answer (score 3):

The encryption, when done properly, is never deterministic. Being deterministic and encrypting always `abc@abc.com` to `fa3GeFi2nb52JH0` would be a weakness, as it would leak information (if you find two equal ciphertexts, then you know that they hold the same plain text. You don't know the exact value, but you know it is the same). Technically you do it with a random value named IV (initialization vector) being passed to the encryption process, but let's not dig deeper.

So, how to deal with your case. You can either:

- accept it the way it is now,
- say you want your encryption to be deterministic even at the cost of being weaker and leaking data.

How to make encryption deterministic? Use constant IV value. I don't know if this can be done in AWS and how, but that would be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Thanks Marek,, will I be able to save the same encrypted values for same data by using constant initialization vector

Comment: Can I get any reference how can I use it to get my thing done...my use case ritenow is if I encrypt the same value...and it is already stored in my db with encrypted values,I want it to be saved as same as above...

Comment: I don't know of this is possible or not,,,,but will save my efforts if achived ...

Comment: I don't know if the AWS SDK allows it. It might not. In case it does not, you would have to dealt with encryption yourself and do it using JCA/JCE yourself. Search in the AWS SDK API if there is a way to pass IV from the outside.

Comment: Hi,,can I use aws kms keys with MySQL asymmetric encrpytion (keyrings).?

Comment: I believe this would deserve another question on SO to be asked.

Answer (score 0):

By using KMS in this way you're performing client side encryption which would put the responsibility on you to decrypt after you have retrieved the data.

At the current time there are no implementations explicitly for using KMS keys within SQL operations, the only support is for encryption at rest of the file storage.

You options are:

- Switch to [native MySQL encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)
- Switch from encrypted to hash to match (not ideal) for this field.
- Perform post processing after narrowing down to decrypt.

Comment: Thanks,,can I use my aws keys in native MySQL encrytion??

Comment: I don't want my keys to be stored at that level,,can I use aws cmk here inside encrypt and decrpt function of MySQL....

Comment: Afraid not, at this time it is not supported via the SQL engine

Comment: What do you mean by perform post processing after narrowing down to decrpt?

Comment: Effectively what you're doing now, add any conditions to your SQL query that do not rely on encrypted data. Then loop through and decrypt before doing comparisons for the encrypted fields

Comment: Yes but the data will increase on daily basis and with each decrpt it is taking 1 sec...won't this make my api slow and slower

Comment: It will if thats the case, in which case using KMS CMK isn't suitable for you at this time

Comment: I have encrpyted RDS instance,,how can I use that to encrpyt my rows of database,,,,will encrpyting the entire database comes under hippa compliance....

Comment: This will encrypt the storage volume, but anyone who can connect to the DB will still be able to see the data unencrypted. This just prevents someone physically connecting to the volume and viewing the data. I believe this will not cover PII although I am not a HIPAA expert.

Comment: Hi crish can I use aws kms keys with MySQL asymmetric encrpytion (keyrings).?????

Comment: Is this possible..using aws kms cmk with MySQL keyrings...I don't want symentric encrpytion of MySQL, I want asymmetric encryption of mysql